# Creating fighting system in very simple Python game

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

So this is the code

```
# TEST.PY

import sys
import random

class Fight(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "\n", "-" * 10
        print "There are two muchachos:"
        print "MUCHACHO1"
        print "MUCHACHO2"
        print "One of them looks wounded or something."

        your_hit_points = 20
        muchacho1_hit_points = 6
        muchacho2_hit_points = 11
        muchacho1 = True
        muchacho2 = True


        while your_hit_points > 0 or (not muchacho1 and not muchacho2):
            print "\n", "-" * 10
            your_attack = random.randint(4,12)
            muchacho1_attack = random.randint(1,4)
            muchacho2_attack = random.randint(4,8)


            attack = int(raw_input("Type 1 to attack MUCHACHO1, 2 to attack MUCHACHO2 >"))

            if attack == 1:
                muchacho1_hit_points - your_attack
                print "You hit MUCHACHO1 for %d hit points." % your_attack

                if muchacho1_hit_points <= 0 and muchacho1:
                    muchacho1 = False
                    print "MUCHACHO1 killed!"
                else:
                    pass

            elif attack == 2:
                muchacho2_hit_points - your_attack
                print "You hit MUCHACHO2 for %d hit points." % your_attack

                if muchacho2_hit_points <= 0 and muchacho2:
                    muchacho2 = False
                    print "MUCHACHO2 killed!"
                else:
                    pass

            else:
                print "DOES NOT COMPUTE"
                pass

            your_hit_points - muchacho1_attack
            print "MUCHACHO1 hit you for %d points, you have %d hit points left." % (muchacho1_attack, your_hit_points)

            your_hit_points - muchacho2_attack
            print "MUCHACHO2 hit you for %d points, you have %d hit points left." % (muchacho2_attack, your_hit_points)

        exit(1)

    a_fight = Fight()
    a_fight.enter()
```

I am having little difficulty. Basically the WHILE loop never finishes and seems like hitpoints of everyone are not subtracting. I have a feeling in my gut that I'm missing something VERY VERY basic because I have been coding for few hours now so I might not see the simple stuff.

I know this could be done better by using more classes or functions but for now I want to do it like this (also sorry for 80+ char lines).

Comment: A piece of advice, try to test your code often, you will see the problem quicker, and you will know where the problem is

Comment: I hate it when dead muchacho keep hitting me. And if I manage to kill them both before they kill me, then their ghosts beat on me forever, even after I'm dead. (check your while logic too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying it's done or that I have the best code style, but I did a few improvements to your code (nice game by the way). 
Some bugs I saw:
Your loop was wrong (you should run the loop while you or at least one muchacho is still alive). 
You need to override muchacho1_hit_points/muchacho2_hit_points every time it takes damage.
You need to check if muchacho is still alive before each round.
This class does not make sense, you could just use a function.
In python `pass` does nothing and can be ignored in your case; it is normally used when declaring container classes that are used later.
Some improvements you could do: catch exception in case the user does not input integer (it now crashes)

```
import random

class Fight(object):
  def enter(self):
    print "\n", "-" * 10
    print "There are two muchachos:"
    print "MUCHACHO1"
    print "MUCHACHO2"
    print "One of them looks wounded or something."

    your_hit_points = 20
    muchacho1_hit_points = 6
    muchacho2_hit_points = 11
    muchacho1 = True
    muchacho2 = True

    while your_hit_points > 0 and (muchacho1 or muchacho2):
      print "\n", "-" * 10
      your_attack = random.randint(4,12)
      muchacho1_attack = random.randint(1,4)
      muchacho2_attack = random.randint(4,8)

      attack = int(raw_input("Type 1 to attack MUCHACHO1, 2 to attack MUCHACHO2 >"))
      if attack == 1:
        if muchacho1:
          muchacho1_hit_points = muchacho1_hit_points - your_attack
          print "You hit MUCHACHO1 for %d hit points." % your_attack
          if muchacho1_hit_points <= 0:
            muchacho1 = False
            print "MUCHACHO1 killed!"
        else:
          print "MUCHACHO 1 is already dead!"
      elif attack == 2:
        if muchacho2:
          muchacho2_hit_points = muchacho2_hit_points - your_attack
          print "You hit MUCHACHO2 for %d hit points." % your_attack
          if muchacho2_hit_points <= 0:
            muchacho2 = False
            print "MUCHACHO2 killed!"
        else:
          print "MUCHACHO 2 is already dead!"
      else:
        print "DOES NOT COMPUTE"

      if muchacho1:
        your_hit_points = your_hit_points - muchacho1_attack
        print ("MUCHACHO1 hits you for %d points, you have %d"
           " hit points left." %(muchacho1_attack, your_hit_points))
        if your_hit_points <= 0:
          print 'You are dead'
          break
      if muchacho2:
        your_hit_points = your_hit_points - muchacho2_attack
        print ("MUCHACHO2 hits you for %d points, you have %d"
            " hit points left." % (muchacho2_attack, your_hit_points))
        if your_hit_points <= 0:
          print 'You are dead'

a_fight = Fight()
a_fight.enter()
```

Comment: Yes I noticed my WHILE loop had wrong conditions.. I still have a little bit problem with that. The reason why it's a class is because it is a part of game and I just pasted relevant piece of code. I will look into exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is `muchacho1_hit_points -= your_attack` and the same for `muchacho2`. Now you are just discarding the result from subtracting.

Comment: Oh that's it. I knew I missed something small. I was tired, thank you.